# Why is this showing only the first input values for each record?

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

**Edit: I’m trying to figure out how to pass the SleepModel record from core data from my log view to my sleep row view. Once that is done, I need to figure out why it’s only displaying the 1st inputs everytime.

I have a CoreData setup where it saves the SleepModel correctly with unique ID, and values. I've checked and the count of SleepModel records goes up with each button click so Im pretty sure CoreData is setup and its saving correctly. However, while it does add another list row to display data, it is only displaying the very first input (not whatever input you put for subsequent entries). Here is what I have for the log view and sleep row views:

```
struct LogView: View {
    
    @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if !coreDataViewModel.savedRecords.isEmpty {
                List {
                    ForEach(coreDataViewModel.savedRecords, id: \.id) { record in
                        SleepRow(sleep:record)
                    }
                } // end list
            } //end if
        }   // end Vstack
        .onAppear {
                coreDataViewModel.fetchRecords()
            }
    }  // end body view
} // end LogView view
```

```
struct SleepRow: View {
    
    @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    Var sleep:SleepModel
    
    var body: some View {
            HStack {
                
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Sleep Results").bold()
                            .font(.system(size:14))
        // Display Hours Slept
                 
                            Text("\(sleep.hoursSlept, specifier: "%.2f") Hours Slept")
                                .font(.system(size:11)).foregroundColor(.red)
```

Comment: You should be passing `record` in to `SleepRow`. That view should not have its own `ForEach`

Comment: I suggest you do the SwiftUI tutorial at https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/ again. Without knowing the very basics of SwiftUI 
you will struggle to code your App UI. And judging by the types and number of your previous questions you are already struggeling.

Comment: I have looked at those tutorials already. The whole CoreData thing really confuses me. And since I'm trying to pull the data from CoreData to display, its confusing me even further..... I changed the 'record' in the row view to 'sleep' after creating a `var sleep: SleepModel`.  But I can't figure out what Im passing to the row view from the logview. I know it goes SleepRow(HERE), but the first value should be record or the second?

Comment: I think I'm on to the right path as I put `SleepRow(sleep:record)` but then it throws an error stating "Cannot convert value of type 'SleepEntity' to expected argument type 'SleepModel'" [SleepEntity is my CoreData entity, and SleepModel is my type I created for my variables

Comment: edit your question, and show us the code you are trying to use now.

Comment: Updated question and code

Comment: remove
 `@StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()` from `SleepRow`,
  you are not using `coreDataViewModel` in `SleepRow`, so there is no need for it.
 If you really need it use `@EnvironmentObject var coreDataViewModel: CoreDataViewModel`.
 
 This is what I explained to you in my answer. Does my answer code not work for you?
 
 Also use `var sleep:SleepModel`, not
 `Var sleep:SleepModel`. In `LogView`, there is no need to have `if !coreDataViewModel.savedRecords.isEmpty{...}`,
  the list will not show anything if `coreDataViewModel.savedRecords` isEmpty.

Answer (score 0):

try this example code, where you have one source of truth, `@StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()` in `LogView`, and pass the model around to `SleepRow` using `.environmentObject(coreDataViewModel)`. Note you do not use `coreDataViewModel` in `SleepRow`, so you could just, not pass the model to it.

```
// for testing
struct SleepModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id = UUID().uuidString // ID variable
        var hoursSlept: Double // Hours slept variable
}

// for testing
class CoreDataViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var savedRecords: [SleepModel] = []
    
    func fetchRecords() {
        savedRecords = [SleepModel(hoursSlept: 1.1),
                        SleepModel(hoursSlept: 2.2),
                        SleepModel(hoursSlept: 3.3),
                        SleepModel(hoursSlept: 4.4)
        ]
    }
}

struct SleepRow: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coreDataViewModel: CoreDataViewModel // <-- here, only if required
    @State var sleep: SleepModel // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Sleep Results").bold()
                    .font(.system(size:14))
                Text("\(sleep.hoursSlept, specifier: "%.2f") Hours Slept")
                    .font(.system(size:11)).foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LogView: View {
    @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(coreDataViewModel.savedRecords, id: \.id) { record in
                        SleepRow(sleep: record)
                    }
                } // end list
        }   // end Vstack
        .environmentObject(coreDataViewModel) // <-- here, only if required in SleepRow
        .onAppear {
                coreDataViewModel.fetchRecords()
            }
    }  // end body view
} // end LogView view
```

Comment: did my answer not work for you?

Comment: Sorry Ive been busy this week with work. No, I think something is messed up with the CoreData file or something. I'm starting a new basic app to learn the basics with not as many variables to do it step by step and learn it as I go. Thanks for the help